# How do I view the source code of a comment?

Tags: support, comments, code-formatting

In a question or answer, I click *edit* to check source markup.  How do I do the same with comments?

Comment: You can dive into data.stackexchange

Comment: Is there something in particular you're looking for? You can't edit other people's comments, and there's no way to see the source through the main UI.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I've seen some formatting in comments I wanted to learn about, but I'm tired of asking people each time I see it.

Comment: And there's not much in the source code, There's not a vast range of formatting options.

Comment: Ask once, can be here, and write it down for next time...

Comment: If you click on the `help` link it gives you a quick summary, or go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting for more

Comment: @user1717828: there is a help link next to the comment box; it tells you everything you need to know about comment formatting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks, never saw that before

Comment: Use this [SOBotics MiniTool](https://tools.sobotics.org/tools/get-body-comment/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot see the source for comments, not on the site itself.

You can search for comments in the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), where comments are retrievable in source form, but the data dump can be up to a week old.

Your best bet is to just read the [comment formatting help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting); the comment box has a *help* link next to it that opens a summary, which in turn links to that page:

<kbd>[image: help link next to comment box circled, arrow to resulting summary, link to further help circled]</kbd>

Comment: I wish there was an easier way to get the source, as I often want to update older comments with new information by copy pasting the old one, editing, making a new command, and deleting the old one.