# Access to the source of comment

Tags: feature-request, comments

Could we have a button to have access to the raw text from a comment?

Sometimes (hard to tell), I want to add a comment to my answer/question, because it would add valuable information, and comments are not designed to stay forever. Or, I want to copy a comment for X reasons. But often, this comment contains Markdown that I want to keep, like a link or code. I believe that it would be an improvement of life quality if we could easily access the source of the comment.

This is something very similar to the edit button, but without the editing feature. So I think it's a reasonable request.

This question is related to *[How do I view the source code of a comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295931/how-do-i-view-the-source-code-of-a-comment)*.

Comment: I don't think this is useful. Often formatting in a comment will not look good in an answer and will have to be formatted differently. There's also the point that if a comment is worth copying into an answer, then it should've been an answer to begin with.

Comment: @coldspeed Comments are supposed to be used to suggest improvements to existing questions/answers. I've seen more than one comment worded in such a way that copying it verbatim into said question/answer was a valid improvement. Just because sometimes you will have to reformat it doesn't mean it's not useful to retain the existing formatting as a starting point.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Created a userscript for this.

You can [install it from GitHub](https://github.com/BrockA/SE-misc/raw/master/Stack%20Exchange%2C%20View%20Comment%20source%20markdown_code.user.js). (Requires *Tampermonkey*, or *Violentmonkey*, or equivalent.)

Or learn more about it on [its Stack Apps page](https://stackapps.com/questions/8296/get-comment-markdown-copy-comment-code-to-clipboard).

Screenshot:

> [image: screenshot of comment markdown display]

Answer (score 36):

I'm glad that I am not the only one who wants this!

**Back story**:

As a non-moderator I used to frequent the 10k tools page (New Answers To Old questions), and used to spot many answers like:

> Thanks @Buddy, your comment asking to do foo, instead of bar helped.

Most of these were on posts that didn't have answers. Using the tip [from this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251598/4099593), I used to edit these into shape as:

> According to [@Buddy's comment](-comment link-):
>
> > Why are you doing bar, when you had to do foo?
>
> Doing foo instead of bar helped me solve the same problem.

In these cases, I used to find it hard to copy over the entire comment until I discovered:

#### [There is a Comments-By-ID API!](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/comments-by-ids)

You can use this endpoint to get the body markdown. However, note that the "body_markdown" field is not selected in the default filter. You need to manually select it. (I personally have bookmarked the API page with all the filters selected.) Dropping just the comment ID into the comment box will retrieve the body markdown for you.

To demonstrate this, I left a [comment on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox#comment1065529_3122). This is [the API call](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments/1065529?order=desc&sort=creation&site=meta&filter=!9Z(-x.Ecg), and the body markdown returned is:

> `A comment *with* some **weird** markdown, to _test_ and help [this user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382478/4099593 &quot;title text won&#39;t work tho&quot;). Look [tag:tags] work too, and so does [tour].`
>
> A comment *with* some **weird** markdown, to *test* and help [this user]([Access to the source of comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382478/4099593) "title text won't work tho"). Look [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) work too, and so does [tour].

(You need to edit it a bit after copying over, else it'll look weird like that.)

Using this API call one can easily create a Userscript that adds a button to your browser. (And for those who don't use Userscripts, I am planning to create a new tool [in one of my projects](https://github.com/SOBotics/MiniTools/issues/4).) Let's hope that one of the Userscripters from Stack Apps see this post.

That said, I feel that implementing this feature would probably be a waste of time. This affects or is useful to only a very small subset of users. I'd rather the developers focus on more pressing issues.

Comment: Well, the [SOBotics MiniTool](https://tools.sobotics.org/tools/get-body-comment/) is available and could be linked in this answer. Careful, though: the CommonMark migration hasn’t been applied to this post and the link for “the API call” needs to be manually edited.

Comment: What do you mean by "title text" and "won't work"?

Comment: @root The mini markdown used in comments allows adding title text, which doesn't work the same way in posts. So you need to edit it a bit before using.

Comment: In your example above, is "this user" the title text?

Comment: @root Nope. The title is the one which is within the double quotes. If you hover over the link, the title text shows up as a small pop up.